# How to use Mapbox style using JSON file

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, angular9, mapbox-gl, angular14

I am trying to add style to the map. I go through the Mapbox site and try to understand how to read JSON style and use it in the application. So this is the JSON file I got from the Mapbox site.

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "name": "Meteorites",
  "metadata": {
    "mapbox:origin": "basic-template-v1",
    "mapbox:autocomposite": true,
    "mapbox:type": "template",
    "mapbox:sdk-support": {
      "js": "0.45.0",
      "android": "6.0.0",
      "ios": "4.0.0"
    }
  },
  "center": [
    74.24426803763072,
    -2.2507114487818853
  ],
  "zoom": 0.6851443156248076,
  "bearing": 0,
  "pitch": 0,
  "sources": {
    "composite": {
      "url": "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8,examples.0fr72zt8",
      "type": "vector"
    }
  },
  "sprite": "mapbox://sprites/examples/cjikt35x83t1z2rnxpdmjs7y7",
  "glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/{username}/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "background",
      "type": "background",
      "layout": {},
      "paint": {
        "background-color": [ ]
      }
    },
    { ... }
  ],
  "created": "2015-10-30T22:18:31.111Z",
  "id": "cjikt35x83t1z2rnxpdmjs7y7",
  "modified": "2015-10-30T22:22:06.077Z",
  "owner": "examples",
  "visibility": "public",
  "draft": false
}
```

so the name of this file is `style.JSON`. my question is how to read this JSON file in our HTML application. When the initial map is load I want to show this style on the UI.

Comment: anyone can help me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to embed it directly in your JavaScript:

```
const style = { version: 8, ... }
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({ style, ... })
```

Comment: is there any way to `import` or embed a reference to the json file (e.g. `import { style } from mapStyle.json`) instead of having all of the code, which is massive, inline in the script?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Perhaps you should ask a whole new question.

Comment: like, instead of embedding the style json directly in the JS file, is there any way to reference or point to the file from JS file so that my JS file isnt 99% the style json?

Comment: Indeed, yes there is.

Comment: how would i go about that? can u point me in the right direction? perhaps link me to the documentation?

Comment: As I suggested above, if you have a question, you should ask a question.